# Bootstrap styling doesn't work for my vs code

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

For every one Why bootstrap styling doesn't work when I click the show preview it seems like i am doing nothing in the code and all things is going good except the styling , there is no styling working , I am using V5.3 in bootstrap , I will be happy if any one can help me !

the code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="./flower.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="sunflower">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the result :

[image]

Comment: The issue is on your end. I copied and pasted your code and it works exactly as intended. Additionally, it would be easier to help if you put the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.